# KEDRO - How to specify an arbitrary binary file in catalog.yml?

Tags: python, data-science, pipeline, mlops, kedro

I'm currently working on a datascience project using LLMs (Large language models). Weights for models usually come in different formats, most frequently .bin or .gguf, and I'd like to keep it that way.

However the only way to store binary files I know is to use type: pickle.PickleDataset like so

```
test_model: # simple example without compression
  type: pickle.PickleDataSet
  filepath: data/07_model_output/test_model.pkl
  backend: pickle
```

I'm not okay with that as I want my model files to be language agnostic.

What would be a correct way to specify arbitrary binary file in catalog.yml?

(additional question: and what if I want to fetch it from certain url or by running some kind of script which fetches it from the net? Should I create a separate pipeline for that?)

Comment: For future reference: GGUF = a format introduced by the llama.cpp team on August 21st 2023 https://www.substratus.ai/blog/converting-hf-model-gguf-model/

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own custom dataset for specific format. I am not familiar with LLM format but I don’t think there is a universal format for binary?

For your second question you may use the APIDataset to fetch from some endpoint. There is a HuggingfaceDataset that you may take as inspiration.

Comment: Is there really no other way but to use it that way? I know that I need a custom dataset for specific format which would allow me to load and pass it as input to function in "decoded" way (e.g. pandas.CSVDataset which loads file as a pd.DataFrame), however, as I see it, my perfect functionality would be just to get a filepath in filesystem, passed to the pipeline node as input / output. Should I implement a custom dataset for that?

Comment: @Quakumei Kedro has no way to know what Python function to use to turn a filepath into a Python object, you have to provide it yourself. And they way to do that is by using datasets, either an existing one or a custom one.